# SyntaxError: Unexpected number when reading CSV

Tags: csv, object

I'm trying to read CSV with Javascript, but I'm getting an error.
Here is my code:

```
fs.readFile('./data/AMZN.csv', async (err,data)=>{
if(err){
    console.log(err)
    return
}
console.log(data.replace("$",""));
```

})

Here is the example of my CSV data:

```
Date, Close/Last, Volume, Open, High, Low
09/11/2020, $3116.22, 5093982, $3208.69, $3217.3409, $3083.98
09/10/2020, $3175.11, 5330741, $3307.219, $3349.89, $3170.55
09/09/2020, $3268.61, 5188675, $3202.99, $3303.175, $3185
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jackl\Desktop\Projects\scraper_cheerio\scraper.js:5:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
```

I've figured out that Javascript perceives $3116 as a string and the following .22 as a property of that string object, which can not be a number and therefore throws "Unexpected number".

But how do I fix it? I've been trying to deal with it for 2 days, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
const AMZN = require("./data/AMZN.csv");
```

The code in the question works fine.